# isSelected() method for checkbox always returns false

Tags: html, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

There is a check box which is displaying as checked already, now when I inspect it shows with **image src.**  in HTML. When I click on the checkbox, it is getting unchecked or checked.

To verify its state, I have written this code, which always brings false even though the checkbox is selected.

```
WebElement chBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath
     ("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/form/fieldset/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[10]/td/img"));

        if (chBox.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("User active check box is already checked");
        } else
            System.out.println("User active check box is not checked");
        }
```

Why?

Comment: Please post html of the element

Comment: Html of element isnt need the java is wrong

Comment: @mfsi_sitamj Below are the html:
<img src="/ABC30/Content/Images/TriStateCheckbox/checked.gif">

Comment: Nevermind i see you're gathering the element and prechecking it. It should always return false is what you're getting at but its returning true?

Comment: @bcar exactly what its reason?

Comment: Thanks for putting the html markup. Can you see whether there is a change in the html before and after selecting the check-box. If yes, can you please the corresponding mark ups (Before selecting and after selecting) here?

Comment: Pardon! There was a typo in the above line :  If yes, can you please post the corresponding mark ups (Before selecting and after selecting) here?

Comment: @mfsi_sitamj in the html it change the code inplace of "Checked.gif" or "Unchecked.gif".

Answer (score 4):

Check the class attribute is getting changed on Check/ Uncheck the check box.  If so, then the  selection state is stored as part of the class

```
    String Class=chk.getAttribute("class");

    if(Class.contains("class name when it is checked"))
     {
        System.out.println("Status: "+chk.getAttribute("checked"));
        //This will return Null, since it is not a real check box(type=checkbox), 
        //so there is no checked attribute in it
     }
    else
     {

        System.out.println("Not Checked");
     }
```

The `isSelected()` method will not handle this type of checkbox, that's why it always returns `false` or not checked(from your point of view)
Refer: [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/webdriver/1398r3xqrk/finding-checkbox-by-isselected-not-working-in-html-5-app-looking-for-suggestions)

Comment: Below are the html of that checkbox and in these its not displaying any classes at tht time of inspecting a check box: 
<td align="left" colspan="2">
<input id="chkIsActive" type="checkbox" name="IsActive" style="display: none;">
<img src="/ABC30/Content/Images/TriStateCheckbox/checked.gif">
<input type="hidden" name="IsActive" value="checked">
<label for="chkIsActive">User is active</label>
</td>
</tr>

Comment: Does the value="checked" getting changed to value="unchecked"(or some other) while toggling the checkbox?

Comment: in the html it change the code inplace of "Checked.gif" or "Unchecked.gif".

Comment: So, with the img src you can check whether it is selected or no, based on that you can click the checkbox

Answer (score 4):

```
WebElement chBox = driver.findElement(By.id("chkIsActive"));

if (chBox.isSelected())
{
   System.out.println("User active check box is already checked");
} 

else
{
   System.out.println("User active check box is not checked");
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It shows the null point exception at the place of if() condition and I manage it via try catch but I think its not a good practice. So, can you please let me know what I do for this??

Comment: There is no id given in the HTML for check box, only image src is there which written in the tag <td>--- </td>

Comment: I think this is the element I am pointing to: `<input id="chkIsActive" type="checkbox" name="IsActive" style="display: none;">`. Anyways, can you please run the following code and paste the output here: `WebElement chBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/form/fieldset/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[10]/td/img")); System.out.println(chBox.getAttribute("src"));` Please run it twice before and after selecting the checkbox and paste the output here.

Comment: When I run it before and after selecting the checkbox then its out come "Null".

Comment: When I check it via some logic in the console it show three checkbox but there are only two checkboxes one for checked.gif and second for unchecked.gif.... I don't understand how to proceed now can you please suggest?

Comment: Please post the HTML for the full page and also if possible post two screenshots pre and post selection of the check-box.

Comment: I dont post the full html code here but posted a code for that particular checkbox and hope it would be helpful.
<td align="left" colspan="2">
<input id="chkIsActive" type="checkbox" name="IsActive" style="display: none;">
<img src="/A30/Content/Images/Checkbox/checked.gif">
<input type="hidden" name="IsActive" value="checked">
<label for="chkIsActive">User is active</label>
</td>

Answer (score 1):

```
       WebElement chck = driver.findElement(By.id("chkRemeberMe"));

        if(!chck.isSelected())
        {                 
                System.out.println(" CheckBox Not Selected");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("CheckBox Already Selected");
        }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to answer it will help to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

What I have found that if your checkbox has `tagname='input'` and `type='checkbox'`, then only `isSelected()` will return a boolean value.

Otherwise, we have to look for another attribute that is getting changed on the check and uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, try the is `isDisplayed()`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath).isDisplayed()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my view, isSelected() returns true only if it is a default selection. It may not work when we select an element and try to check if it is selected or not.
Correct me if I am mistaken.
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the xcode you are writing. Check if you can get a more unique xcode for the checkbox only something like

"/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/form/fieldset/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[10]/td/img[@type='checkbox']"

A checkbox xtype should mostly end with type=checkbox for isSelected to work

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean select = driver.findElementByXPath("xpath").isSelected();
Assert.assertEquals(select, "true");
```

If is selected the checkbox then this case will not get fail.

Answer (score 0):

When `isselect()`  Always Returns `False`  do this

```
 WebElement chkbox =  sc.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[name()='circle'])[5]"));
      
      
      if(!chkbox.isSelected())
      {
          chkbox.click();
          
          System.out.println("True");
      }
      else {
          System.out.println("false");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

On python using image of element to find if it is checked.

```
import PIL
import io

chBox= driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH,value="/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/form/fieldset/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[10]/td/img")#find checkbox
image_binary = chBox .screenshot_as_png#get raw image of checkbox
img = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_binary))#get pil image from raw image
colors=img.getcolors()#list pixels count an color
for color in colors:
    if color[1]==(40, 97, 205, 255):#find blue
        print("checkbox blue")
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

Your findElement() call is missing .click to check or select the check box or radio

```
WebElement we  = findElement(By.xpath("some path));
we.click();
we.isSelected() => true
```

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the question.