# How to get the checked/unchecked status of a check box when it is disabled using Selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've run into this simple situation that I have a **disabled** checkbox and I want to get its checked/unchecked status.

```xml
<input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" name="chkOne" data-ng-model="service1" disabled="true" type="checkbox">
```

However, code like

```java
boolean checked = mywebelement.isSelected();
```

does not work and always return `true`.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396301/isselected-method-for-checkbox-always-returns-false-why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working fine.

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid']")).isSelected());
```

It is printing true when checked and false when unchecked.

I have tried with this code

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("C://sample.html");
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid']")).isSelected());
```

Comment: I was using serenity webelementfacade, it's not working. Selenium webelement works fine.